# How to insert dates into a date field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRO5v.jpg)
Sent_Date: This field will usually gets update whenevr there is any alert sent, If No alert then that perticular day there wouldnot be any entry of Alert Sent date.

Requirement : Though there is no alert, i want the dates to be inserted in the table, may be with corresponding values as NULL/0. I have no issues

AS per the picture attached. After JAN 12 the next alert sent date is JAN 20. 
But for me i need dates to be inserted with blank data IF NO alerts.

Please help me

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what the problem is or how that picture illustrates the problem.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I copy a table from Production to support environment and in that a column is ( Sent_Date). In this column, if there is any dates missing..  i wanted to insert with some dummy data.

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing that?  What have you tried and what isn't working?  So far it just sounds like you're just asking how to insert a record into a table, which would be covered by any introductory SQL examples.

Comment: OK. will comeback with test results

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a query that returns the count of alerts for each day in a given range, you can use a Calendar table, or a cte to generate the date range you want, and join to the source of your alerts and count the alerts for each day.

```
declare @fromdate date = '20170101'
declare @thrudate date = '20170131'

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(datetime,dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate))
     ,[NextDate]=convert(datetime,dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)), @fromdate))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto      /* 100 days */
      cross join n as kilo     /* 2.73 years */
      --cross join n as [tenK]    /* 27.3 years */
   order by [Date]
)

select d.Date
     , count(*) as Alerts
from dates d
  left join alerts a
    on a.sent_date >= d.Date
   and a.sent_date <  d.NextDate
group by dates.Date
```

Calendar and Numbers table references

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)